# How to send information from a html form to a MySql database (XAMPP)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, xampp

I'm very close to being with this mini-project I have. It's basically a survey and I want to know how do I send the information to a database? Right now I have XAMPP installed on a Windows server 2008 R2. How do I get:

**RACE/ETHNIC GROUPS** (Check One):

```
<ul id="race">
<li><input type="radio" name="race" value="latino" /> Hispanic or Latino</li> <li><input type="radio" name="race" value="white" /> White</li> <li><input type="radio" name="race" value="black" /> Black or African American</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="race" value="asian" /> Asian</li> <li><input type="radio" name="race" value="mraces" /> Two or more Races</li> <li><input type="radio" name="race" value="native"/> Native American Indian/Alaskan Native</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="race" value="pac" /> Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander</li> <li><input type="radio" name="race" value="other" /> Other</li> <br/>
</ul>
```

into the MySql database? I'm so very close but I don't know any php and very, very limited knowledge of Javascript. I have to surround it in a form tag and then make a submit button? Can anyone help in this last step? Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually you are in the first step towards injecting those values to a database, I suggest you first read some tuts regarding PHP. Basics I insist.

Comment: For the DB part, start reading on [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for ex. Also, personal sidenote, although commonly accepted I think you should drop the usage of "race" as identifying ethnical, i.e. social and cultural, differences; they're not synonyms, and it's not a matter of being politically correct or not. But this is offtopic here, sorry

Comment: Please check this link, explains how to insert the records with form elements http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$username = "your_name";
$password = "your_password";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$database = "exampleDb";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or 
            die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db($database,$dbhandle) or 
            die("Could not select examples");

 CREATE DATABASE `exampleDb`;
 USE `exampleDb`;
 CREATE TABLE `cars` (
      `id` int UNIQUE NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(40),
      `year` varchar(50),
      PRIMARY KEY(id)
 );

 INSERT INTO cars VALUES(1,'Mercedes','2000');
 INSERT INTO cars VALUES(2,'BMW','2004');
 INSERT INTO cars VALUES(3,'Audi','2001');    
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, access the MySql database server by using the following commands:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'userid', 'password');
mysql_select_db(database_name);
```

Then, you can use the insert statement of MySql server by using the insert command like:

```
$sql=mysql_query("insert into table_name(column_name, column_name2, column_name3) values('value1', 'value2', 'value3')");
```